# How can I prevent Tkinter slave widgets from dictating their own positions?

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-layout

So I have two frames, a centered text frame and a toolbar with buttons in it. I want the toolbar to be on top side, so I tried `self.toolbar.pack(side='top', pady=60)` but it doesn't seem to be enough.

What happens is that the buttons, who are slaves of the toolbar frame, seem to be dictating their own position : if I `pack` one left, it goes on the left side of the entire application. Instead, I would like to be able to place once my toolbar frame, and then `pack` my buttons, side by side, so using something like the `side` attribute that currently change their global position.

How can I achieve this? Is my OOP approach bad written?

The whole block:

```
import tkinter as tk


class ToolbarButton(tk.Button):

    def __init__(self, master, text, pixelref, *args, **kw):
        super(ToolbarButton, self).__init__()
        self.master = master
        super(ToolbarButton, self).configure(text=text, image=pixelref, height=20, width=20, compound='center')


class MainApplication(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent

        # Textframe
        self.text_frame = tk.Frame(root, width=600, height=790)
        self.text_frame.pack_propagate(False)
        self.text_widg = tk.Text(self.text_frame, width=1, height=1)
        self.text_widg.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

        # Toolbar
        self.toolbar = tk.Frame(root)
        self.pixel = tk.PhotoImage(width=1, height=1)

        self.bold_button = ToolbarButton(self.toolbar, 'B', self.pixel)
        self.bold_button.pack(side='left', padx=4)
        self.italic_button = ToolbarButton(self.toolbar, 'I', self.pixel)
        self.italic_button.pack(side='left', padx=4)
        self.underline_button = ToolbarButton(self.toolbar, 'U', self.pixel)
        self.underline_button.pack(side='left', padx=4)

        # Packing
        self.toolbar.pack(side='top', pady=60)
        self.text_frame.pack(expand=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    MainApplication(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. We can't run your code as posted. Your description sounds like you are doing everything right, so we need to be able to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @BryanOakley added!

Comment: That code isn't minimal - code to set the state is irrelevant to the question, as is defining multiple custom fonts. Also, please do not link to code on another site.

Comment: I didn't want to drown the main question with code. I'll try to replace the current code with a new minimal one

Comment: _"I didn't want to drown the main question with code."_ - that's why we request a _minimal_ example. You can easily remove 15-20 lines of that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone explained me the issue: the ToolbarButton class wasn't instantiating properly.
A way to correct this - and improve the syntax too:

```
class ToolbarButton(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, master, text, pixelref, *args, **kw):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.configure(text=text, image=pixelref, height=20, width=20, compound='center')
```